# Number of slaves 0 when I mpirun my R code that test rmpi

Tags: r, mpi, openmpi, snow

After some trials, I was able to install Rmpi package on my computer using the following code:

```
R CMD INSTALL -l /storage/home/***/.R Rmpi_0.6-7.tar.gz --configure-args="--with-Rmpi-type=OPENMPI --disable-dlopen --with-Rmpi-include=/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/openmpi_4.1.4_gcc-9.3.1/include --with-Rmpi-libpath=/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/openmpi_4.1.4_gcc-9.3.1/lib"
```

I tried to run the following test code:

```
# Load the R MPI package if it is not already loaded.
if (!is.loaded("mpi_initialize")) {
  library("Rmpi")
}

ns <- mpi.universe.size() - 1
mpi.spawn.Rslaves(nslaves=ns)
#
# In case R exits unexpectedly, have it automatically clean up
# resources taken up by Rmpi (slaves, memory, etc...)
.Last <- function(){
  if (is.loaded("mpi_initialize")){
    if (mpi.comm.size(1) > 0){
      print("Please use mpi.close.Rslaves() to close slaves.")
      mpi.close.Rslaves()
    }
    print("Please use mpi.quit() to quit R")
    .Call("mpi_finalize")
  }
}
# Tell all slaves to return a message identifying themselves
mpi.bcast.cmd( id <- mpi.comm.rank() )
mpi.bcast.cmd( ns <- mpi.comm.size() )
mpi.bcast.cmd( host <- mpi.get.processor.name() )
mpi.remote.exec(paste("I am",mpi.comm.rank(),"of",mpi.comm.size()))

# Test computations
x <- 5
x <- mpi.remote.exec(rnorm, x)
length(x)
x

# Tell all slaves to close down, and exit the program
mpi.close.Rslaves(dellog = FALSE)
mpi.quit()
```

On my HPC I run the following:

```
qsub -A open -l walltime=6:00:00 -l nodes=4:ppn=4:stmem -I
module use /gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/modules
module load openmpi/4.1.4-gcc.9.3.1 r/4.0.3
mpirun -np 4 Rscript "codes/test/test4.R"
```

But then I get the following error indicating that I only have 1 number of slaves:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
By default, for Open MPI 4.0 and later, infiniband ports on a device
are not used by default.  The intent is to use UCX for these devices.
You can override this policy by setting the btl_openib_allow_ib MCA parameter
to true.

  Local host:              comp-sc-0222
  Local adapter:           mlx4_0
  Local port:              1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
By default, for Open MPI 4.0 and later, infiniband ports on a device
are not used by default.  The intent is to use UCX for these devices.
You can override this policy by setting the btl_openib_allow_ib MCA parameter
to true.

  Local host:              comp-sc-0222
  Local adapter:           mlx4_0
  Local port:              1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
By default, for Open MPI 4.0 and later, infiniband ports on a device
are not used by default.  The intent is to use UCX for these devices.
You can override this policy by setting the btl_openib_allow_ib MCA parameter
to true.

  Local host:              comp-sc-0222
  Local adapter:           mlx4_0
  Local port:              1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
By default, for Open MPI 4.0 and later, infiniband ports on a device
are not used by default.  The intent is to use UCX for these devices.
You can override this policy by setting the btl_openib_allow_ib MCA parameter
to true.

  Local host:              comp-sc-0222
  Local adapter:           mlx4_0
  Local port:              1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device.

  Local host:   comp-sc-0222
  Local device: mlx4_0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device.

  Local host:   comp-sc-0222
  Local device: mlx4_0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device.

  Local host:   comp-sc-0222
  Local device: mlx4_0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: There was an error initializing an OpenFabrics device.

  Local host:   comp-sc-0222
  Local device: mlx4_0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  Choose a positive number of slaves.
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  Choose a positive number of slaves.
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  Choose a positive number of slaves.
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  Choose a positive number of slaves.
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
```

I have tried specifying different number of np's but still get the same error. What could be the cause here?

============================================================

(EDIT)
It seems that my original command to load the modules also load intel/19.1.2 and mkl/2020.3. If I unload them, I do see that `OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4`.

```
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module purge
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module load openmpi/4.1.4-gcc.9.3.1 r/4.0.3
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module list

Currently Loaded Modules:
  1) openmpi/4.1.4-gcc.9.3.1   2) intel/19.1.2   3) mkl/2020.3   4) r/4.0.3



[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ mpirun -np 4 env | grep OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ type mpirun; mpirun --version; mpirun -np 1 env | grep OMPI
mpirun is /opt/aci/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.2.254/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpirun
Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2019 Update 8 Build 20200624 (id: 4f16ad915)
Copyright 2003-2020, Intel Corporation.
LMOD_FAMILY_COMPILER_VERSION=19.1.2
LMOD_FAMILY_COMPILER=intel



[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module purge
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module load openmpi/4.1.4-gcc.9.3.1 r/4.0.3
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module unload intel mkl
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ module list

Currently Loaded Modules:
  1) openmpi/4.1.4-gcc.9.3.1   2) r/4.0.3



[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ mpirun -np 4 env | grep OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE
OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4
OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4
OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4
OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4
[****@comp-sc-0220 work]$ type mpirun; mpirun --version; mpirun -np 1 env | grep OMPI
mpirun is /gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/openmpi_4.1.4_gcc-9.3.1/bin/mpirun
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.4

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
OMPI_MCA_pmix=^s1,s2,cray,isolated
OMPI_COMMAND=env
OMPI_MCA_orte_precondition_transports=954e2ae0a9569e46-2223294369d728a3
OMPI_MCA_orte_local_daemon_uri=4134338560.0;tcp://10.102.201.220:58039
OMPI_MCA_orte_hnp_uri=4134338560.0;tcp://10.102.201.220:58039
OMPI_MCA_mpi_oversubscribe=0
OMPI_MCA_orte_app_num=0
OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4
OMPI_MCA_orte_num_nodes=1
OMPI_MCA_shmem_RUNTIME_QUERY_hint=mmap
OMPI_MCA_orte_bound_at_launch=1
OMPI_MCA_ess=^singleton
OMPI_MCA_orte_ess_num_procs=1
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_SIZE=1
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_SIZE=1
OMPI_MCA_orte_tmpdir_base=/tmp
OMPI_MCA_orte_top_session_dir=/tmp/ompi.comp-sc-0220.26954
OMPI_MCA_orte_jobfam_session_dir=/tmp/ompi.comp-sc-0220.26954/pid.8212
OMPI_NUM_APP_CTX=1
OMPI_FIRST_RANKS=0
OMPI_APP_CTX_NUM_PROCS=1
OMPI_MCA_initial_wdir=/storage/work/k/****
OMPI_MCA_orte_launch=1
OMPI_MCA_ess_base_jobid=4134338561
OMPI_MCA_ess_base_vpid=0
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK=0
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_RANK=0
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_NODE_RANK=0
OMPI_MCA_orte_ess_node_rank=0
OMPI_FILE_LOCATION=/tmp/ompi.comp-sc-0220.26954/pid.8212/0/0
```

But if I run the same test4.R again, I get the following error:

```
/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.3-intel-19.1.2-mkl-2020.3/R-4.0.3/../install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.3-intel-19.1.2-mkl-2020.3/R-4.0.3/../install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.3-intel-19.1.2-mkl-2020.3/R-4.0.3/../install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.3-intel-19.1.2-mkl-2020.3/R-4.0.3/../install/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[63743,1],0]
  Exit code:    127
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

============================================================

(EDIT 2)
I changed my `module load` command again to `module load openmpi/4.1.4-gcc.9.3.1 r/4.0.5-gcc-9.3.1`. With this newer version of R I ran my test4.R script again with `mpirun -np 4 Rscript "codes/test/test4.R"`. It is now returning a new error message as follows:

```
[1] "/storage/home/k/kxk5678/.R"
[2] "/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.5-gcc-9.3.1/install/lib64/R/library"
[1] "/storage/home/k/kxk5678/.R"
[2] "/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.5-gcc-9.3.1/install/lib64/R/library"
[1] "/storage/home/k/kxk5678/.R"
[2] "/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.5-gcc-9.3.1/install/lib64/R/library"
[1] "/storage/home/k/kxk5678/.R"
[2] "/gpfs/group/RISE/sw7/R-4.0.5-gcc-9.3.1/install/lib64/R/library"
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
[1] 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
Error in mpi.comm.spawn(slave = system.file("Rslaves.sh", package = "Rmpi"),  :
  MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
Calls: mpi.spawn.Rslaves -> mpi.comm.spawn
Execution halted
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[62996,1],1]
  Exit code:    1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: start printing `mpi.universe.size()`, how big is the universe?

Comment: I added a line```print(mpi.universe.size())``` to my test script and it prints "1"...

Comment: this is fishy. If I understand correctly your PBS script, you allocate 16 MPI tasks but starts only 4, so I would expect universe size is 16 (and you really want to spawn 12 slaves e.g. `MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE` - size of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`). What does (from the same PBS script) `mpirun -np 4 env | grep OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE` reports?

Comment: I ran ```mpirun -np 4 env | grep OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE```, but it returned nothing. I tried re installing Rmpi with the command same as in main post, but get the following error (which I think I did have in my initial try):
```WARNING: There is at least non-excluded one OpenFabrics device found,
but there are no active ports detected (or Open MPI was unable to use
them).  This is most certainly not what you wanted.  Check your
cables, subnet manager configuration, etc.  The openib BTL will be
ignored for this job.```

Comment: that's odd. what if you `type mpirun; mpirun --version; mpirun -np 1 env | grep OMPI`

Comment: note you can `export OMPI_MCA_btl_openib_allow_ib=true` before invoking `mpirun` in order to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Hi, I have added an EDIT to my original post since I would run out of characters. It seems that my original command to load the modules also load intel/19.1.2 and mkl/2020.3. If I unload them, I do see that ```OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=4```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the package `pbdMPI` in an R session on the login node and run the following translation of the `Rmpi` test code into the use of `pbdMPI`:

```
library(pbdMPI)

ns <- comm.size()

# Tell all R sessions to return a message identifying themselves
id <- comm.rank()
ns <- comm.size()
host <- system("hostname", intern = TRUE)
comm.cat("I am", id, "on", host, "of", ns, "\n", all.rank = TRUE)

# Test computations
x <- 5
x <- rnorm(x)
comm.print(length(x))
comm.print(x, all.rank = TRUE)

finalize()
```

You run it the same way you used for the `Rmpi` version: `mpirun -np 4 Rscript your_new_script_file`.

Spawning MPI (as in the `Rmpi` example) was appropriate when running on clusters of workstations but on an HPC cluster the prevalent way to program with MPI is SPMD - single program multiple data. SPMD means that your code is a generalization of a serial code that is able to have several copies of itself cooperate with each other.

In the above example, cooperation happens only with printing (the `comm...` functions). There is no manager/master, just several R sessions running the same code (usually computing something different based on `comm.rank()`) and cooperating/communicating via MPI. This is the prevalent way of large scale parallel computing on HPC clusters.

Comment: pbdMPI is now up to date on CRAN so no need to get the GitHub version. I updated the answer above.